# Grails Groovy GORM ColumnTransformer Postgresql inet macaddr

Tags: hibernate, grails, mapping, grails-orm, inet

We have a postgres database with column types like inet and macaddr

We have generated Hibernate POJOs to use and can map these data types using

```
@ColumnTransformer(write="inet(?)")
```

The mapped field in the POJO is a String.

This works fine but I'd really like to use Grails Domain Classes instead.

Any idea if there is an equivalent to the ColumnTransformer I can use?

Thanks